# SageMaker tuning job cannot use P2 or P3 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, auto-tuning

I am trying to use AWS SageMaker Hyperparameter tuning job. I can use C5 instance, however, when trying to use either p2 or p3 I get this error.

```
{{botocore.errorfactory.ResourceLimitExceeded: An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CreateHyperParameterTuningJob operation: The account-level service limit 'ml.p3.2xlarge for training job usage' is 2 Instances, with current utilization of 0 Instances and a request delta of 5 Instances. Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit.
}}
```

Does anybody have idea about it?

Comment: You probably need to request a limit increase, you can find the instructions at this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation in our account so we had to request for using the instances and increasing the available resource from AWS.